# Filling a form field with the current URL via javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to populate a hidden field in a form that I have created with the current URL of the page including all the UTM tags.

I seem to be having trouble when trying to get the value of the URL into the field, for some reason it keeps reporting null

```
var urlnew = window.location.href;
document.querySelector("input[name='url_hidden']").value = "urlnew";
```

if I hard code a value it works correctly and submits but it's just anytime i try to use something else

Comment: You might want to try `document.querySelector("input[name='url_hidden']").value = urlnew;` . urlnew is a variable and not string!

Comment: I just tried and im getting "cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: When is this piece of code running ? Make sure this is being executed after the DOM is loaded(only then your input field is available for the querySelector) or if the element is added dynamically ensure that this code executes after the input field is added to the DOM.

Comment: At the moment I'm just trying to do it via console. I have added this but now it comes back undefined again.

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
var urlnew = window.location.href;
    document.querySelector("input[name='url_hidden']").value = urlnew;
});

Comment: @NewAtCode can you check the working example as answer I posted ?

Comment: @NewAtCode First, `document.querySelector("input[name='url_hidden']")` should return an input element(indicates element is present in DOM)  then you can assign value using `.value`. All the below examples will work here, but it may not in your code, what matters is the sequence, element should exist when you assign value. Your error says element is null - ""cannot set property 'value' of null ". Also, check once if you are making any typo in input name.

Comment: Hi, sorry to be so dumb about it but if I take my example and replace the variable name after value it works, so I would assume that the rest of it works correctly, if I then replace the "urlnew" including the "" that's when I get the error

Comment: Not sure why, can't think of anything without reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quote:

```
<html>
<body>
  <input type=text name=url_hidden>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlnew = window.location.href;
    document.querySelector("input[name='url_hidden']").value = urlnew;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried and im getting "cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: @NewAtCode This only means that the element you are trying to access using querySelector doesn't exist! Please check the query selector string input

Answer (score 0):

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const username_el = document.querySelector("input[name='username']");
  const password_el = document.querySelector("input[name='user_password']");
  const hidden_el = document.querySelector("input[name='hidden_url']");
  
  const url = window.location.href;
  
  hidden_el.value = url;
  
  window.alert(`${username_el.value} - ${password_el.value} - ${hidden_el.value}`);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
 Username:  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
 
 <br>
 
 Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password" placeholder="Password">
 
 <br>
 
 Hidden URL: <input type="hidden" name="hidden_url" id="hidden_url">
 <br>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, this still came back undefined for me

Comment: Please post a reproducible snippet. It's not possible to debug without knowing what & where you're doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You might as well want to populate the value attribute:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='url_hidden']").value = urlnew;
```